# git-http-backend with apache authentication not working

Tags: apache-2.4, git

I am trying to use git-http-backend over apache. I want a publicly readable repository but some authenticated user may push. I have the following config:

```
SetEnv GIT_PROJECT_ROOT /home/username/git
SetEnv GIT_HTTP_EXPORT_ALL
SetEnv REMOTE_USER $REDIRECT_REMOTE_USER
ScriptAlias /git/ /usr/lib/git-core/git-http-backend/

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} service=git-receive-pack [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /git-receive-pack$
RewriteRule ^/git/ - [E=AUTHREQUIRED:yes]

<LocationMatch "^/git/">
        Order Deny,Allow
        Deny from env=AUTHREQUIRED

        AuthType Basic
        AuthName "Git Access"
        AuthUserFile /home/username/.htpasswd
        AuthGroupFile /home/username/.htgroup
        Require group committers
        Satisfy Any
</LocationMatch>
```

My repository can be cloned anonymously, but there is not authentication during push, anyone seems to be able to push to the repo. I tried enabling `http.recievepack` to `false` in the repo, but then even cloning fails with a 403 error.

How do I solve the problem?